# Cannot get rid of "no-unused-expressions" - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in ReactJS, I'm following a tutorial and i created a stateless component for a video list that's have some images and related texts.

The Error was:

> Line 9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an
>   expression  no-unused-expressions

And the component is:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './VideoList.css'

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import CardInfo from '../CardInfo/CardInfo'

const VideosTemplate = (props) => {
    return props.data.map( (item,i) => {
        <Link to={`/videos/${item.id}`} key={i}>
            <div className={styles.videoListItem_wrapper}>
                <div className={styles.left}
                style={{
                    background: `url(/images/videos/${item.image})`
                }}>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.right}>
                    <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Link>
    })
}

export default VideosTemplate;
```

And the line 9 is:

```
<Link to={`/videos/${item.id}`} key={i}>
```

Note: When i tried to remove everything in map function everything is work, just when i use item it cause an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is returned from `map` callback. `<Link ...>` creates React element that isn't used anywhere. It should be either implicit return:

```
return props.data.map( (item,i) => (
    <Link to={`/videos/${item.id}`} key={i}>
    ...
```

Or explicit return:

```
return props.data.map( (item,i) => {
    return <Link to={`/videos/${item.id}`} key={i}>
    ...
```